# Separating data from different sites

Tags: database, portal

We are creating a web solution that contains large number of users, their events, calendars and content to be managed. This solution can be white-labeled and can be sold to other vendors as a services, i.e. Though the hosting is in our SINGLE server but thy will have their own administrator and there own users and separate contents, that are completely disconnected to the other vendors. For example we are going to host the solution as

www.example.com/company1

www.example.com/company2

www.example.com/company3

The question is should we use different database for different company, or we should use single database for managing all the company.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use separate databases for each company, unless you are offering some sort of service where the companies know that data is being pooled.

This is a question of data protection.  No matter how much you swear that one company can only see their data in the table, you may not be able to convince prospective clients of this fact.

In addition, you need to keep the options open of running the databases on different servers.  You don't want peak performance at one company to affect another company.  Or, you don't want a special change for one company -- which might require bringing down the application with their knowledge -- to affect other clients.